# Learn playing guitar right from the mac?

Tags: macos, music

I am eager to learn playing guitar by the help of my MBP.
Is there a software around helping you to play mp3 files of your choice?
P.S: I know nothing about guitars and bought one out of sudden yesterday.

Answer (score 6):

You can use GarageBand to learn guitar. If you have iLife 11 with the new version of GarageBand, it comes with [basic guitar lessons](http://www.apple.com/ilife/garageband/#basic-lessons).

Answer (score 2):

Do you run linux on your MBP, too? Perhaps, you can test tuxguitar. It's something like GuitarPro, but open source. You can find tabs all over the web. You can open GuitarPro tabs with tuxguitar. It's is very good to learn guitar. If you run ubuntu, use apt-get to install.

Answer (score 0):

You should give Capo a try http://supermegaultragroovy.com/products/Capo/ - it's pretty awesome! Lets you adjust a track's tuning to match your guitar e.g. if the track is dropped tuned and lets you slow a track right down while you practice playing along with it.